# Erro na instalação do chatterbot

Tags: python, cmd, instalador, pip, chatterbot

Estou tentando instalar o chatterbot mas estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Mariana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r5apde_f\blis\

Meu setuptools tá atualizado, então, não tenho a menor ideia do que pode ser o problema nem como resolver.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, seu setuptools está desatualizado.

O código abaixo deve resolver o problema.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Quando eu tentei, deu isso: **Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\mariana\lib\site-packages (40.9.0)**

Comment: Tenta utilizar: `python setup.py build` 
`python setup.py install`
Peguei essa referência [aqui](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/913#issuecomment-321441775) e aparentemente deu certo.